# convert string[] to base64

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file.readalllines

I am opening a file encoded in base64 and I need to decode it

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(open1.FileName);
```

is there anyway to do this?
I have tried doing this.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Convert.ToBase64String(open1.FileName));
```

Comment: `Convert.ToBase64String()` will take collection of bytes and will convert it to base64 string.

Comment: oh how do i turn the lines variable into base 64 instead

Comment: `Convert.FromBase64String` takes a base64 string  and converts it to byte array. Note that it requires 1 string and your whole file should be read as one (`File.ReadAllText`)

Answer (score 0):

you question is not clear

if you want to convert `string[]` to array of base64 you can do this :

```
public static string[] ToBase64(string[] text)
{
    var encodedArray = new string[text.Length];

    for (var index = 0; index < text.Length; index++)
    {
        var line = text[index];
        var encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line));
        encodedArray[index] = encoded;
    }
    return encodedArray;
}
```

this returns your array with each line encoded in base64.
and to reverse it :

```
public static string[] ToString(string[] encodedString)
{
    var decodedArray = new string[encodedString.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < encodedString.Length; i++)
    {
        var line = encodedString[i];
        var decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(line);
        decodedArray[i] = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
    }

    return decodedArray;
}
```